# Is there any indication that stormtrooper armor protected the wearer from harm?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

In the Star Wars movies stormtroopers tend to die from a single hit no matter from what weapon or on what location. A single blaster hit anywhere on their armor is all that is needed to take them out. Even hitting them with a wooden stick or small stones seems to be lethal to them.

If that is the case, what is their armor good for? Has there been any example of a stormtrooper's armor protecting him from any harm?

Durasteel armor would be very effective against [gunpowder weapons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13690/why-dont-they-use-gunpowder-in-the-star-wars-universe), this is why slug-throwers are [hardly ever used](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13699/4004), but as they don't face such weapons on a regular basis, what threats are on a battlefield against which the stormtrooper's armor provides protection?

Comment: Highly related, arguably a dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38509/31936. Also related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14454/31936.

Comment: As for the last paragraph, the armor effectively forces the Rebels to use blasters instead of (possibly cheaper and more easily obtained) slugthrowers. If the stormtroopers don't wear armor the Rebels can just use slugthrowers against them. So the armor protects them against the *threat* of slugthrowers, even if they are never actually attacked by such weapons.

Comment: Dust storms, maybe?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that they are protected from embarrassment.  At least nobody can see their faces when they are missing the side of a barn.

Comment: Stormtrooper armor is extremely effective. We're just not sure what it's effective against.

Comment: @Null : I would argue it is not an exact duplicate. The linked questions are about the general usefulness and features of stormtrooper armor. This would be about finding an example in canon where the armor saved the wearer from harm. And even if you would really like to keep it closed as a duplicate, your first link in your comment would be a much better choice than the currently used link.

Comment: @vsz I agree that the first link I provided would be a better dupe choice. However, I didn't actually vote to close this. You'll need to take it up with Adamant and Valorum or petition to re-open this question on meta.