# Can slugthrowers penetrate stormtrooper armour?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers, armor

Many Star Wars fans claim no (including on this site, I see the claim often backed by no citation), as does one journal entry for *Star Wars Rebels: Rebel Journal by Ezra Bridger* (at least according to Wookieepedia's article https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Slug#cite_note-EBJ-2; any quotes from the actual book would arguing one way or the other be greatly appreciated). However, in *Aftermath*, Jas Emari kills many stormtroopers with her slugthrower.

Here are some quotes from the book (this happens several times in *Life Debt*):

- Page 332 (Jas is armed with a slugthrower):

  > Already, they’re waving her toward the Halo. A pair of forest troopers comes up a long spiraling ramp—one is already on her, so she cracks him hard enough with the butt of her gun that his helmet spins. The other gets a point-blank shot to the chest plate. It splits in half and he goes down, his armor shattered and smoldering as he twitches.
- This is made more explicit on page 364:

  > Jas takes down troopers left and right with her slugthrower. Jom is altogether more brutal—he and the Wookiee get right in there, scraping bodily with their foes, flinging white-armored incompetents left and right often into one another.

Comment: what journal entry for Star Wars Rebels are you talking about? A link to that would be helpful, otherwise I think the question is invalid because you post your own canon proof. So really, the question is, which resource is accurate?

Comment: Edited to include a link. I haven't read the *Star Wars Rebels: Rebel Journal by Ezra Bidger*, and I am not sure I trust Wookiepedia, especially when it comes to the power of Stormtroopers. The claim that Stormtroopers are impervious to slug throwers is very common, and I have read it on this site before: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13695/why-would-a-slug-thrower-be-more-effective-against-a-lightsaber-jedi-than-a-blas/13699#13699 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140670/is-there-any-indication-that-stormtrooper-armor-protected-the-wearer-from-harm?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I've not read the Bridger journal, but, assuming it's a first hand account from a street rat teenager on an outworld planet, it's possible the slugs he is familiar with / has access to are different from the ones a professional bounty hunter has access to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, [Aftermath](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/7846/aftermath-star-wars-by-chuck-wendig/ebook) is considered canon.

So if a slugthrower penetrates Stormtrooper armour in Aftermath, then a slugthower can indeed penetrate Stormtrooper armour.

---

[Jas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jas_Emari) uses a custom made slugthrower, so it's feasible that this weapon could be more powerful than a standard slugthrower:

> As a bounty hunter, Jas was a skilled sniper who wielded a self-made long-range rifle that was based on an old Czerka slugthrower. Emari was also good at hand-to-hand combat when circumstances demanded. She was also a good planner who was able to build an improvised map and plan using household objects. In her line of work as a bounty hunter, Jas had to kill numerous individuals

Although, I can't see if it's explcitly stated that it is. Main characters usually use custom or unique weapons. I'm sure there's a trope for that somewhere.

Comment: Aftermath is definitely canon

Comment: So basically it is canonical and the question answers itself?

Comment: @Edlothiad if Aftermath is canonical, then the question does answer itself.

Comment: @Daft I mean it is canonical, it's part of Journey to Star Wars: The Force Awakens

Comment: You'd have to check the Aftermath comic itself to see if her weapon is custom-made and only based on a slugthrower, rather than being an actual slugthrower. If so, the question is rendered moot, since Jas' weapon wouldn't technically be a slugthrower anyway. This would also leave us with the fortunate position where Star Wars: Rebels canon is also correct and we don't have conflicting canon sources.

Comment: Good point. Wookiepedia cites some log entry from *Rebels* to back up their claim that Slugs cannot kill Stormtroopers, without a quote. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Slug#cite_note-EBJ-2

Comment: @Edlothiad The claim that slug throwers cannot kill stormtroopers is extremely common, and I read it all the time on this site, as well as Quora such as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140670/is-there-any-indication-that-stormtrooper-armor-protected-the-wearer-from-harm?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13695/why-would-a-slug-thrower-be-more-effective-against-a-lightsaber-jedi-than-a-blas/13699#13699 I did not mean to answer my own question, but instead see if anyone has sources. Wookiepedia claims Slugs cannot penetrate stormtrooper armour in canon.

Comment: Aftermath comic - @DisturbedNeo? Have they comic-ized the Aftermath novels?

Comment: I remember reading that the stormtrooper armor is very effective against Tusken rifles. However, the Tusken raiders were adept marksmen and were able to kill troopers by aiming/hitting the lenses of the helmets.

Comment: Also isn't chewbackas weapon also considered a slug thrower? (that one surely as hell has no problems with storm trooper armor....or anything else that is)

Comment: @Thomas I believe Bowcasters do throw a solid quarrel. However, (from memory) the bowcaster charges/envelops the quarrel with plasma energy (making it look like a blaster bolt). The quarrel is driven by magnetic force towards the target where it explodes on contact. I believe it is more related to a 40MM grenade launcher rather than a "slug thrower". The sheer explosive force and inertia of the quarrel (speed*mass) is enough to incapacitate troopers or at least knock them down.

Comment: I meant Novel, sorry. And yes, a Bowcaster does exactly that, making them more powerful than standard blaster rifles, let alone a slugthrower.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, *some* slug throwers can.**

"Slug throwers" as a category includes every single gun currently in existence on Earth. There's a wild difference in power between a 9mm pistol and a .50 sniper rifle.

I found [a video at LiveLeak.com](https://www.liveleak.com/view?i=462_1306094689) showing a range of different guns, from a 9mm pistol to a .50 sniper rifle, being fired at a "60 litre water filled plastic drum".

The 9mm puts a hole in the barrel, and a little water leaks out, but that's about it. Somewhat larger guns, such as the AK-47, actually lift the barrel off the ground and create large sprays of water. A smaller sniper rifle rips a large tear in the far side of the barrel. The .50 cal sends the barrel into the air. It lands on its side, nearly ripped in half, largely empty of water.

As a consequence of this range in power, real body armor is rated by how much force it can stop. Most "bulletproof" vests actually only stop handguns. From [the Wikipedia article on bulletproof vests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletproof_vest#Rifle_resistant_armor):

> Because of the limitations of the technology a distinction is made between handgun protection and rifle protection. See NIJ levels 3 and 4 for typical requirements for rifle resistant armor. Broadly rifle resistant armor is of three basic types: ceramic plate-based systems, steel plate with spall fragmentation protective coating, and hard fiber-based laminate systems. Many rifle armor components contain both hard ceramic components and laminated textile materials used together.
>   ...
>   Because of the use of ceramic plates for rifle protection, these vests are 5–8 times as heavy on an area basis as handgun protection. The weight and stiffness of rifle armor is a major technical challenge.

So, in your story reference, the fact that Jas can penetrate stormtrooper armor with a custom long rifle shows that at least *some* slug throwers can penetrate stormtrooper armor, but it certainly does not imply that any arbitrary slug thrower would succeed as well.

Comment: And even though a vest will stop a handgun bullet, the lucky wearer still gets to absorb the kinetic energy.  It would still not feel good.  A "wimpy" 22lr generates ~100 foot/pounds of energy at the muzzle a 9mm several hundred, a centerfire rifle one to 3 thousands of foot pounds of energy. A heavy weigth boxer can generate 1000-1500 ft/lbs of energy with a punch...